# I have a list and want make a Formular for the users, from the list

Tags: list

i have created a List in Sharepoint. (Name, Street, City, Date)
Now i want to have a Formular from this list. -> Users can type in their datas.

2. And i want to have, that user x only can see the formular and nothing else. (User Y can see the Formular + a Webpage) How can i realize that?

Answer (score 0):

You can build custom view/edit forms in SharePoint designer. Go to the list, then in the Forms section click new. You can choose what type of form to make and which forms should be default. Then you can use security trimming to hide the section that should only be seen by a certain user group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I realize this without the SharePoint Designer? Only with Sharepoint?

Comment: Yes, but I think it would be more complicated. A few options. 1) Go to the List, in the ribbon click "Customize Form" and it will allow you to customize in Infopath. I'm not sure how you'd check for validation, but you can probably write code behind to check whether the logged-in user is in a group. 2) Use JQuery and SPServices in the form, find the current user's group memberships, and hide individual elements if the user is not in the required group. (This is the method I would use if I couldn't use designer.) 3) Design custom forms in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You helped me a lot with your answer :)

Comment: Awesome. Then could you select it as the answer over next to the upvote/downvote buttons on the left?  Thanks!